# Live-wire - real time chat not responding correctly

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

I'm trying live-wire to see how to implement it in my upcoming project. The idea is a simple chat ( user enters a body of text and click send then the message will be at the bottom of the chat)

So far everything works fine till I hit the click send button.

Here is picture before I click on send
[image]

and here is what happens after I click send

[image]

I feel like the issue is in this part of code where I send the message to the live-wire blade

```
  @foreach ($messages as $message)
            @if($message->isYou())
                <livewire:conversations.conversation-message-own :message="$message" :key="$message->id" />
            @else
                <livewire:conversations.conversation-message :message="$message" :key="$message->id" />
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

here is the component

```
public $body= "";
public $conversation;

public function mount(Conversation $conversation)
{
    $this->conversation = $conversation;
}

public function reply()
{
    $this->validate([
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
    $message = $this->conversation->messages()->create([
        'user_id' => user()->id,
        'body' => $this->body,
    ]);
    $this->emit('message.created',$message->id);
    $this->body = "";
}
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.conversations.conversation-reply');
}
```

}

last is listening to the event component:

```
 class ConversationMessages extends Component
{

public $messages;

public function mount(Collection $messages)
{
    $this->messages = $messages;
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.conversations.conversation-messages');
}
protected function getListeners()
{
    return [
    'message.created' => 'prependMessage',
    ];
}

public function prependMessage($id)
{
    $this->messages->prepend(Message::find($id));
}
```

}
the issue in the inspect log is

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
> but I think it's not related to the chats data!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post more of the component in that listen to the message created event? I would like to see the public attribute messages, the render function and also the blade

Comment: thanks for your response! can you check my repo please at https://github.com/Abdulaziz-almoshen/SocialApp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the keys passed to the conversation-messages components. Livewire breaks trying to render these components, even if separated with ifs. You will need to generate different keys, like a string  `'message-own-' . $message->id` and `'message-'. $message->id` . I tested your code with `rand()` data:

```
@foreach ($messages as $message)
    @if($message->isOwn())
        <livewire:conversations.conversation-message-own :message="$message" :key="rand() * $message->id" />
    @else
        <livewire:conversations.conversation-message :message="$message" :key="rand() * $message->id" />
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. interesting because I'm passing a collection of model. I just tried what youy wrote collection of models got an error  `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Livewire\Conversations\ConversationMessages::mount() must be of the type array, object given, called in /Users/mac/Desktop/laravel/SocialApp/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireManager.php on line 109 (View: /Users/mac/Desktop/laravel/SocialApp/resources/views/conversations/show.blade.php)`  also changed from ConversationController collection to array but got an error that users not found

Comment: I will run your code here in a couple of hours, to check if this is really the problem

Comment: Sorry, my couple hours take longer. But the error was in the keys of the components

Comment: it's ok :) I think so the keys and prepend are making some messy work. I will try to find out how to fix it.